# Skill Alexa with personal information

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I wish I could have those who download the skill insert a data to be used by the skill.
Example:
username: joker
team: barcelona

and use "joker" and "barcelona" in the skill.

Answer (score 0):

You can.

Use intents & slots to get the information.

Use the attributes manager and a persistence adapter to remember them between sessions.

Those are all covered in the Cake Time tutorial.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/tutorials-code-samples/build-an-engaging-alexa-skill

It'll get difficult if you're trying to let them use non-words like "Pwn3dR4t" but with the right carrier phrases you should be able to set up a username intent that lets them say a pretty wide variety of words.

Comment: can these customizations be included in the settings? after skill installation?
Each user enters (written) the information I need to customize the skill experience.

Comment: If you want the user to be able to write them on a keyboard, then you'll need to set up an external service, like a web site, where they can set up an account and enter that info, then link your skill to that with Account Linking. https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/understand-account-linking.html